# Issue with RDD - list index out of range

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using values obtained from one RDD in another. I use the first RDD to calculate averages and do a `.collect()` to fetch it into a variable called `z`.

When accessing `z` however, I get an error, `list index out of range`.

What am I doing wrong?

```
avgtuples = summedtuples.map(lambda (ct, (Sx, Sy)): (((Sx*1.0)/ct), ((Sy*1.0)/ct)))
z = avgtuples.collect()
newmap = reducedhostbyte.map(lambda (h, (x, y)): (n, get_vals(x, y, z[0], z[1])))
```

The value of `z` is `[(24.910157132138149, 474512.76637794758)]`.

Comment: Did you at least check if z isn't empty?

Comment: [(24.910157132138149, 474512.76637794758)]

Comment: `z` is a list that contains all of the elements in the RDD. Do you want elements 0 and 1 only? Assuming they are present, as @eliasah pointed out

Comment: alright, then you can see there is only one element in `z`, that tuple. `z[1]` doe not exists (`z[0][1]` does). Explain what you intend to do with `z` in general, please

Comment: i want to send each of these values to the function get_vals. Is z[0][0],z[0][1] the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `z` is `[(24.910157132138149, 474512.76637794758)]`, it is a list with a single element. So `z[1]` causes an `IndexError`.

That single element (`z[0]`) is a two-element tuple, so presumably you want to access those two elements as `z[0]` and `z[1]`. If so, this is what you need:

```
z = avgtuples.collect()[0]
```

(Note the `[0]` at the end. It takes the first (and only) element of the list.)

It's strange that you would have a single-row RDD (`summedtuples`) in the first place. There is probably more that could be improved in your code, but that's outside of the scope of the question.